# MutationObserver too slow to redefine navigator property in a dynamic iframe?

Tags: javascript, navigator, mutation-observers

I'm making some updates to a Chrome extension that re-defines navigator.userAgent,
and I came across this behavior when replacing DOMNodeInserted with MutationObserver ..

This question is generic and doesn't require testing from a Chrome extension.

The best way to explain this behavior is to navigate to:
https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/

Then ... using the console run the following javacript code, and check the response from iframe> navigator.userAgent:

**DOMNodeInserted works fine, the iframe > navigator.userAgent is switched:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event)
{
    if (event.target.tagName == 'IFRAME')
        for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++)
            try { Object.defineProperty(window.frames[i].navigator, 'userAgent', {value:'TEST'}); } catch(e) {}
});
```

**MutationObserver doesn't work, the iframe > navigator.userAgent  is NOT switched:**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    for (var mutation of mutations)
        for (var item of mutation.addedNodes)
            if (item.tagName == 'IFRAME')
                for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++)
                    try { Object.defineProperty(window.frames[i].navigator, 'userAgent', {value:'TEST'}); } catch(e) {}
});
observer.observe(document, { childList:true, subtree:true });
```

*Excuse the crude iteration through window.frames and not the actual event.target*

I believe it has to do with MutationObserver being too slow, but I don't know how to fix this ?!

UPDATE --------------------------------------------------------------

I have tried the suggestions without luck:

https://jsfiddle.net/12t5jx38/

See the script in action on the page:

https://gofile.io/d/9VUosT

First what happens without an injected script, then your suggestions, then the original using DOMNodeInserted ...

This is the result I'm trying to achieve, but without using DOMNodeInserted.

UPDATE 2 ------------------------------------------------------------

https://jsfiddle.net/st0ud9zq/

I believe there's no way to achieve the desired UA patch via MutationObserver.

Comment: Since their code is using the iframe synchronously, you can't use MutationObserver. You can try registering a content script with "world": "MAIN", "all_frames": true, "match_origin_as_fallback": true, "run_at":"document_start" and see if it runs inside the iframe, then patch the UA. I'm afraid though it won't work due to https://crbug.com/1261964.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,- Yes unfortunately it doesn't work when I try that either. So it looks like there's no alternative currently for patching UA via anything other than MutationEvents ...

Comment: Well, you can patch createElement or whatever else they're using...

Comment: Right, but this is meant as a universal solution to patch any UA method that uncovers the real UA string. It’s in my chrome extension with id: mjfahldkpjhcnfbbmdhpjolcjpcfhcpj

Comment: Yeah so you'll need to patch all methods that you know. It'll be less reliable than DOMNodeInserted theoretically though if someone finds an unpatched method.

Answer (score 0):

Note: check the error within catch due to `CORS`, you might not have access to `contentWindow` of iframes

If your scripts register the observer after the iframe is there, `MutationObserver` won't detect anything. In that case go modify the available frames if you have access to their `contentWindow`. For those that might be added at some point after your script, `MutationObserver` should work.

I am not able to reproduce the behavior you had, SO snippet complains about CORS iframes so here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/u5pz9sry/)

Here is the code

```js
const daFrame = document.createElement("iframe"),
      body = document.body,
      obs = new MutationObserver(function(muts){
        muts.forEach(mut => {
          if(mut.type !== "childList"){return}
          mut.addedNodes.forEach(n => {
            if(!(n instanceof HTMLIFrameElement)){return}
            Object.defineProperty(
              n.contentWindow.navigator,
              "userAgent",
              {value: "whateva"}
            )
          })
        })
      });

obs.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});

//push this to macrotask to make sure it executes after above
setTimeout(() => document.body.appendChild(daFrame), 0);

setTimeout(() => console.log(`userAgent =`, window.frames[0].navigator.userAgent), 3000);
```

I used `setTimeout` to introduce a delay to initiate the `MutationObserver` incase the DOM node (in this case the iframe) might be inserted before the observer starts.

you can also push a `Promise` to an outer array and resolve those pushed promises if you do not want to use setTimeout. But that's not the topic of this question.

PS: It looks like the Mutation Observer is registered way after the DOM node is there, and on top you are using a text to dynamically set the content of the script and execute it there. In these cases divide the task in 2 parts, first scan the currently available iframes and do whatever you need to do on them and THEN register the Mutation Observer. Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/0bxyejga/

```js
const daFrame = document.createElement("iframe"),
            scriptEl = document.createElement("script");

const scriptContent = `
Array.from(window.frames).forEach(frame => {
    Object.defineProperty(
    frame.navigator,
    "userAgent",
    {value: "whateva"}
  )
});
const body = document.body,
      obs = new MutationObserver(function(muts){
        muts.forEach(mut => {
          if(mut.type !== "childList"){return}
          mut.addedNodes.forEach(n => {
            if(!(n instanceof HTMLIFrameElement)){return}
            Object.defineProperty(
              n.contentWindow.navigator,
              "userAgent",
              {value: "whateva"}
            )
          })
        })
         });
obs.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
`
const srcBlob = new Blob([scriptContent], {type: "text/javascript"}),
            contentURL = URL.createObjectURL(srcBlob);

document.body.appendChild(daFrame);

scriptEl.type = "text/javascript";
scriptEl.onload = async function(){
    console.log("script loaded");
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  Array.from(window.frames).forEach(frame => console.log(`userAgent = `, frame.navigator.userAgent))
}

scriptEl.src = contentURL;

document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

Comment: I made small changes and now have this JSFiddle to illustrate: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4uxze7d0/
If you comment out the DOMNodeInserted you will see it's not changing UA in time.

Comment: You should certainly be also able to reproduce my 2 code chunks on that page by opening developer tools and going to console and then pasting one or the other piece of code, then changing between "[aggressive] iframe navigator.userAgent" and something else to see it's not applying the string using MutationObserver.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8y7r326n/
 Just a small fix to use event.target.contentWindow.navigator :)

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/ax43Lh12/1/
Why it works? because observer observes BEFORE the node added. If you add the node and observe on the same event loop it will not fire. If you have the option to add the frames within async function or setTimeout, do that. Otherwise, instead of relying on MutationObserver to detect iframe nodes that are added TOO early into the event loop, directly query the window.frames, why bother with MutationObserver or ANY event listener if the node is already there?

Comment: Yes, but I don't control when the iframe is added (by the web page), and the code on that page checks UA right after adding it. So my only option to modify UA is to use DOMNodeInserted as MutationObserver doesn't seem to work. It's for a Chrome extension that re-writes the UA and it's meant as a generic override for any web page. This was just my observation after changing DOMNodeInserted to MutationObserver in my existing extension, id: mjfahldkpjhcnfbbmdhpjolcjpcfhcpj

Comment: Ok, how about dividing your code in 2 parts, 1st part deals with nodes that are already added to the DOM at the time your script runs by directly running a function: `window.frames(frame => //do something)`. And the second part initiates the mutations observer to watch out for frames that might be added at some time in the future

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, here's a portion of the code that's getting injected to pages on document start. https://jsfiddle.net/q9xmu2pj/ There's no way to replace DOMNodeInserted with MutationObserver so that result will be twice "123" ... The real UA will leak when using MutationObserver.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h7z6jmrq/
Replaced DOMNodeInserted with MutationObserver, and failure observed ...

Comment: Please get them OUT OF any event listener or observer. In the textcontent of the script do : `Array.from(window.frames).forEach(d => /*do the UA change*/))`. No EventListener, no mutation observer. The node is already there

Comment: I think if you look closer at https://jsfiddle.net/q9xmu2pj/ you will see there’s 3 catch all types, plain window.frames, DOMContentLoaded, and DOMNodeInserted. You will also see it works, until only DOMNodeInserted is changed to MutationObserver.

Comment: I can understand the intention and I attached a working example here: jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/0bxyejga . This is also now attached in the answer. You cannot just add a textContent on script and call it a day. Second of all, the example you gave is so unreadable using those pluses and not even formatted, at least use template literal like I did.

Comment: Looks good on paper, but see my update with video showing that it doesn't work as it's not able to modify the UA and have the page think that the UA is actually different. By the way textContent does work when it's injected, but I have modified it anyways.

Comment: I just went over the address you gave  https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/ and pasted my code in the console and inspected the value of `window.frames[0].navigator.userAgent` and it gave 'whateva'. What is the issue here? Are you trying to do reverse ddos for real?

Comment: Your code, pasted on that page I listed (in Chrome) shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'navigator') when switching between the different UA methods. window.frames[0].navigator.userAgent also shows unchanged. I am confused why yours is showing the modified UA, I've included a video.

Comment: No it does not. I just took a screen shot. I verified that it works in Chrome. Here is the screen shot. https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/vkxpcsud/

I will not reply anymore, this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: This is the reason that it does not work, DOMNodeInserted runs before MutationObserver ...

https://jsfiddle.net/st0ud9zq/

If you can adjust this example code by modifying only what's inside of scriptContent to make it work then please do so ... Your example works but it's completely invalid for what I'm trying to achieve and it doesn't help as seen in the JSFiddle.